# Cronjob for python script not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have an ubuntu box I'm trying to setup a cronjob for. When I do crontab -e this is what I am using as the instructions. I need it run every 11 minutes.

```
0/11 * * * * python /path/to/file/foo.py
```

At the top of the python script I have put:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And I have done:

```
sudo chmod a+x foo.py
```

I'm not really sure how I am supposed to figure out how it ran correctly. The script works fine on my local, and appends something to a text file. I have been checking the txt file and nothing appears. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you have the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/python`), you don't need to state explicitly `python /path/to/file/foo.py`. Maybe change it to `/path/to/file/foo.py`. Without the `python` prefix. You can also check `/var/log/syslog` to see what `cron` did.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wasn't sure if it's on the system path (usually), but **if** it's not, this should be more robust I suppose.

Comment: The txt file is in /var/foo/foo.txt

I am using file.write('/var/foo/foo.txt', 'a')

Comment: @vikingcode: thanks, that clears a commonly made mistake out of the way then.

Comment: @Martijn, sorry I am frustrated and its been a long day. I figured out what was wrong, its a new Ubuntu box and one of the import lines didn't have that library installed and was crapping out. 

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Tip to avoid future frustrations: install a `sys.excepthook` handler that logs problems to a file. You then can catch any such problems early. See https://gitorious.org/plebia/plebia/commit/0dda013d63a35d639d94734ac5d8c3b99c91eeb4 for a sample implementation.

Comment: I have a similar problem to execute a command in crontab but I have to use execute by going inside a virtual environment like
$ cd myprojectdirectory

$ source venv/bin/activate

$cd projectdirectory/appdirectory

$python manage.py notify_email

how shall I include the above commands in crontab to schedule for every one minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron line

```
0/11 * * * * python /path/to/file/foo.py
```

will fire only when the minutes equals 0. To make it fire every 11 minutes use

```
*/11 * * * * python /path/to/file/foo.py
```

Comment: This answered par to the problem. Thanks